# Returning member object with a getter function as const but it is modifiable

Tags: c++

I have a class with a private member that is an object and I have set up a corresponding getter:

```
class lepton {
private:
  TLorentzVector _p;
  ...

public:
  ...
  const TLorentzVector& p() const { return _p; }
};
```

and the TLorentzVector class of course has its own functions and variables, let's say that `SetStuff(...)` is a function, for example. Let's also say that `SetStuff(...)` modifies the object's private variables. My program is allowing me to call:

```
....
lepton foo;
foo.p().SetStuff(...);
....
```

I'm wondering how this is possible given that the getter `p()` is const.
Is this a bad way to have a getter which allows for modification of the class member? I ended up with this setup because at another point in my program I want to add the `_p` (TLorentzVector object) variable of two objects like so:

```
lepton lep1;
lepton lep2;
....
auto combined_four_vector = lep1.p() + lep2.p();
....
```

And if I just had the getter in the lepton class defined as:

```
TLorentzVector& p() { return _p; }
```

I am not able to add the TLorentzVector objects.

Comment: Is `SetStuff` a const function? If yes, then `foo.p().SetStuff(...);` should not compile. If no, then how can it modify internal data?

Comment: This is very confusing. `foo.p().SetStuff(...)` shouldn't compile (assuming `SetStuff` is not `const`, as you imply), while `lep1.p() + lep2.p()` should whether or not the return type is `const`. In any case, you can have two overloads, one `const` and one not, to allow modification of the vector in a non-`const` lepton, and read-only access in a `const` lepton.

Comment: "And if I just had the getter in the lepton class defined as: ... I am not able to add the TLorentzVector objects."
Yes you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a non-constant overload and a constant overload (unless you have any reason not to define a non-constant overload):

```
class lepton {
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    TLorentzVector const& p() const { return _p; }
    TLorentzVector& p() { return _p; }
};
```

In this way for functions and operators that take a `lepton const&` only the `const` overload will be available, maintaining the const-safety of the object.

---

For example, the following will work as expected:

```
lepton foo;
foo.p().SetStuff(...);
```

and assuming an `operator+` defined on `TLorentzVector const&`, the following will also work just fine:

```
auto res = lep1.p() + lep2.p();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first member function be `const TLorentzVector& p() const { return _p; }` ?

Comment: @kebs That's equivalent. `const T&` and `T const&` have the same semantic.